# How to remove flag secure token in cookies Laravel Inertia in Cpanel Hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project with Laravel Inertia Vue in my cpanel hosting. But i see there is have secure flag with my token in cookies like screenshot below:
[image]

It affects the post, update, delete method in my web, and return 419 page expired. If i remove both secure flag, then its working normally.

Why i ask this, because in tutorial demo website or other Laravel website, i see that secure flag is not checked, like this screenshot below:

[image]

How to remove the secure flag? I have already setting my session.php, and run

```
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

but its still not working

My session config:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

My env:

```
...
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
...
```

I use php 8.0 on my hosting. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks before.

Note: I have 2 project with same stack in the hosting, and both is not working now, error 419.

Comment: You're trying to fix the wrong problem. Don't make it less secure; figure out why your routes aren't working with a secure cookie. I suspect you're accessing some routes as HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: hm, how to check that sir? in my env file, its already have ```APP_URL=https://websitename.com``` and i forced access to https

Comment: Try setting your trusted proxies to `*` to see if it helps. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Comment: i try ```protected $proxies = '*';``` its still error 419 sir

Comment: Are you passing the CSRF token with the requests?

Comment: No sir, i read from https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection it say ```The easiest way to implement this is using server-side middleware. Simply include the XSRF-TOKEN cookie on each response, and then verify the token using the X-XSRF-TOKEN header sent in the requests from axios.

Some frameworks, such as Laravel, do this automatically, meaning there is no configuration required.```

Comment: Actually its working on my local computer, but not working on hosting @ceejayoz

Comment: is that save if i add ```mydomain.com/*``` in except verifyCrsfToken middleware sir?

i mean so its only allowed the myself mydomain.com @ceejayoz